# Cantidad de veces de un caracter en una sentencia SQL

Tags: sql

Hola tengo un problema con una sentencia sql quiero que me muestre el numero de veces que se repite una letra en este caso `H` en una tabla

```
SELECT  SUBSTR(TRIM(CURP),11,1) AS GENERO  FROM * `tbl_name`
```

hay solo muestra la letra H o M porcada registro de la tabla

Comment: podrias mirar por favor [tour] y [ask]? deberias especificar que base de datos es, y mostrar tambien como esta compuesta tu tabla.

Comment: Los títulos engloban el contenido y se describe en el cuerpo del mensaje, los títulos no son para poner toda la descripción... Espero que este título encaje mejor. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Con el fin de dar respuesta a tu inquietud sería necesario utilizar la sentencia "GROUP BY" como te enuncio a continuación:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(CURP),11,1) AS GENERO,
      count(*) AS Empleados 
FROM NombreDeTuTbl
GROUP BY SUBSTR(TRIM(CURP),11,1)
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Bibliografía: http://deletesql.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13

Comment: Tal vez seria mejor esperar a que OP explicara un poco mas que tiene su tabla...

Comment: si @gbianchi tienes razón, en realidad es poca información la que brinda el usuario que pregunta... espero actualice la pregunta para complementar mejor mi respuesta. Saludos y muchas gracias por tu apreciación.